# Key-value store as primary database

Tags: java, database, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am about to start a project where read and writes will be large and frequent, Thereby looking around I found that in-memory databases are made exactly for that purposes itself. Investigating a little more took me to redis.

Redis seems pretty cool(Just started reading, alot to know about it though). But I have primarily seen only relational databases and think of data in term of tuples and relations (I think this I can learn with time).

I have following questions right now:

1. Can I use only redis to store my data ?

   - Reason why I am asking is that every article I have seen use Redis/memcached as an intermediate layer for caching.
   - Can I just rely on redis to persist my data through out ?
2. Where to host/run redis database ?

   - Since Redis is an in-memory database, its requirement of host will definitely be different than applications that require more processing. Hosts which have more RAM will definitely be better here.
   - So where do people normally go on to host their database ?
   - Elasticcaching from AWS, can this be used to host redis(as a primary database, not just caching layer)
3. Any resources ?

   - I always ask this, I found lots of good documents online, but nothing really good to start with. Please share any good resource if you are aware of.

Comment: [The Redis website](http://redis.io/) is generally the best place for Redis documentation. Much of it is written by the guy who originated Redis (Salvatore Sanfilippo, also known as Antirez), and he documents it in a very clear and even-handed manner, with minimal marketing nonsense. There’s [a list of docs](http://redis.io/documentation) on the site, and specifically on using Redis as your only data store, take a look at http://redis.io/topics/persistence and http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html

Comment: Adding to @PaulD.Waite - look at Muut's post too: https://muut.com/blog/technology/redis-as-primary-datastore-wtf.html

Comment: @ItamarHaber: that’s a decent case-study.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, Seems like to use In-memory database as only datastore requires alot of risk management, Thereby I am considering option of using redis backedup with mysql db. Is it a good choice, Also I don't know how to manage data between these two stores. Right now I am thinking to asynchronously push data to mysql.

Comment: What do you consider to be "large and frequent?" Sharded relational databases scale incredible well these days.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I use only redis to store my data ?

It depends on your requirements but with 150+ NoSQL database available, I suspect redis is not your only option.

> Reason why I am asking is that every article I have seen use Redis/memcached as an intermediate layer for caching.

It is faster than JDBC, but do you need it to be faster?

> Can I just rely on redis to persist my data through out ?

You could, it depends on your reliability requirements.  e.g. some organisations only trust traditional RDBMS databases.  Note: you need to have redis on multiple servers to pretect against a failure.

> Where to host/run redis database ?

Wherever you like.

> Since Redis is an in-memory database, its requirement of host will definitely be different than applications that require more processing. Hosts which have more RAM will definitely be better here.

I would normally put a NoSQL instance on the same machine.  The amount of RAM you give it depends on how much data you need.

> So where do people normally go on to host their database ?

Across multiple servers for redundacy, they can be shared with the applications.

> Elasticcaching from AWS, can this be used to host redis(as a primary database, not just caching layer) Any resources ?

I would ask them.

> I always ask this, I found lots of good documents online, but nothing really good to start with. Please share any good resource if you are aware of.

There is no one resource as there is no one answer. If there was, there would be 150+ NoSQL databases.

Disclaimer: I have work another NoSQL key-value store which is persisted as well as in memory and is dramatically faster (if you need that sort of thing) It is also simpler to use/deploy.
https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map

Comment: Thanks @peter, Your answer does answers alot of my questions.

Comment: One last thing, I am currently building my application using jdbc as primary database and will plug in redis if I am facing performace issues. Do you think its right approach ?

Comment: @HarshitSyal That is a good approach.  Start with the simplest solution and optimise for performance based on specific requirements and measures.  Often you might guess what could be a bottleneck later, but often this turns out to be the 5th or 10th biggest bottleneck, and spending more time finding and working on the top one will make more difference.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use only redis to store my data ?

It is possible to configure [Redis persistence RDB + AOF](https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/) and with that option you can use Redis as a primary database, but be aware that having RDB + AOF will be impacting Redis performance for write operations and there might be another issues mapping you in-memory data to disk and vice versa.

Redis is in-memory storage and, as you already know, there are some hurdles making it primary database. Also you can try ready-to-go solutions like AWS MemoryDB, which is reliable database and Redis at the same time. If you can't use solutions like that, I don't recommend focusing effort try store data only on Redis and have data backed up by regular, well understood database.

> Where to host/run redis database ?

Redis is a single threaded solution, so your host should provide you large available memory and 2-4 cpu for start. You will need to monitor performance and scale resources as needed, from my experience usually memory that going to be bottle neck.

> Any resources

- https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/
- https://aws.amazon.com/memorydb/